# How can I remove USB flash drive write protection?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have tried `Diskpart` but its not working.

I have also tried the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies` but I cant find `StorageDevicePolices`

Comment: Can you provide more detail?  For example, flash drives often go into write protect mode when they fail, so knowing it's in write protect because you put it there and now can't undo it is a different problem from a drive that suddenly did it on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Even fairly new flash memory devices can actually fail.

If all spare blocks has failed in a USB/CF/SD-flash/disk/memory device then it may turn into a read only device. By that you can still read out your data fairly safely, without causing the device to fail (immediately/completely).